# jason output to export csv file

Tags: parsing

Below is my code to export some fields from DB to csv output file.

The Gui has controls to export the file in csv format. But the output csv file is blank except for headers. Why is that?

```
Public class somecontroller
{


try
      {

         List<CompanyContact> companyContactList = contactService.getContacts(companyType);
         List<CompanyContactsExportDTO> companyContactsExportDTOS = createCompanyContactsExportDTO(companyContactList);
         writeCsvResponse(response,fileName,CompanyContactsExportDTO.class,companyContactsExportDTOS);
         log.info("Finished exporting contacts for " + companyType + "company Type");
      } catch(Exception e)
      {
         log.error("Error producing contacts report", e);
         //Close CSV writer so it can flush & print headers in case no rows had been printed before.
//         csvRecordWriter.close();
         //add extra row stating there was an error
         response.getWriter().println();
         response.getWriter().print(buildCsvErrorMessage());
      }
      finally
      {
         response.getWriter().close();
      }

private void writeCsvResponse(HttpServletResponse response, String csvFileName, Class annotatedPojoClass, List results) throws Exception
   {
      response.setContentType("text/csv");
      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", csvFileName));
      response.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
      response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
      response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.PRAGMA, "no-cache");
      response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.EXPIRES, "0");

      CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
      CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(annotatedPojoClass).withHeader();
      mapper.writer(schema).writeValue(response.getWriter(), results);
   }


}


private List<CompanyContactsExportDTO> createCompanyContactsExportDTO(List<CompanyContact> companyContactList)
   {
      List<CompanyContactsExportDTO>  companyContactsExportDTOS = new ArrayList<>();
      for(CompanyContact cc:companyContactList)
      {
         CompanyContactsExportDTO dto = new CompanyContactsExportDTO();
         dto.setCompany(cc.getCompany().getCompanyName());
         dto.setContactType(cc.getCategory());
         dto.setEmail(cc.getParent().getEmail());
         dto.setPhone(cc.getParent().getPhone());
         dto.setInfo(cc.getInfo());
         dto.setFirstNameLastName(cc.getParent().getFirstName()+ " " +cc.getParent().getLastName());
      }

      return companyContactsExportDTOS;
   }
```

but the export file is blank.

The Jason Object is like below

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
      "company",
      "contactType",
      "info",
      "firstNameLastName",
      "phone",
      "email"
})
public class CompanyContactsExportDTO
{
   private String company;
   private String contactType;
   private String info;
   private String firstNameLastName;
   private String phone;
   private String email;

   public CompanyContactsExportDTO()
   {
   }

   public String getCompany()
   {
      return company;
   }


   public String getContactType()
   {
      return contactType;
   }


   public String getInfo()
   {
      return info;
   }

   public String getFirstNameLastName()
   {
      return firstNameLastName;
   }


   public String getPhone()
   {
      return phone;
   }


   public String getEmail()
   {
      return email;
   }






   public void setContactType(String contactType)
   {
     this.contactType = contactType;
   }

   public void setPhone(String phone)
   {
      this.phone = phone;
   }

   public void setEmail(String email)
   {
      this.email = email;
   }

   public void setInfo(String info)
   {
      this.info = info;
   }

   public void setCompany(String companyName)
   {
      this.company = companyName;
   }

   public void setFirstNameLastName(String firstNameLastName)
   {
      this.firstNameLastName = firstNameLastName;
   }
}
```

and the object derived from DB has below structure

```
public class CompanyContact
{
   private Integer id;
   private String info;
   private boolean isActive;


   private CompanyDTO company;//this is embedded object

   private String category;

   private Contact parent;//this is another embedded object

   public CompanyContact()
   {
   }

//It has other getter and setter methods
}
```

please let me know what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: i found the issue.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer, so that if another programmer has the same problem, they can see how you solved it?